# how to style text after <br>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `clone()` and I'm close to it but I cannot replace the text, it is showing both:

```js
var td_clone = $('.ms-vb').clone();
$('span', td_clone).remove();
$('br', td_clone).remove();
var name = $.trim(td_clone.text());
$("td").append(name.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="80%" style="padding-bottom: 3px" class="ms-vb">
            <span class="ms-announcementtitle">
                title is here
            </span>
            <br>
            by hey
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Result:

```
title is here 
by hey BY HEY
```

While I am expecting:

```
title is here 
BY HEY
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cba4m/33/)

Comment: Why exactly are you cloning the elements when you seem to want to alter them in place?

Comment: that's A way I found to style text after `<br>`, if you know of any better/faster way, fire on an answer

Comment: Anyway, you make a clone. You remove the span and the text inside the span. You then remove the break, and all that is left is the textNode containing `by hey`. You take that string, uppercase it, and append it to the HTML you already have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing it correctly, just target the textNode directly

```js
var node = document.querySelector('.ms-vb br').nextSibling;

node.textContent = node.textContent.toUpperCase();
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="80%" style="padding-bottom: 3px" class="ms-vb">
            <span class="ms-announcementtitle">
                title is here
            </span>
            <br>
            by hey
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

A little more jQuery'ish would be to use `contents()`, which actually returns comment and text nodes, but there's really no need for this when the plain JS solution is so simple, and the jQuery version contains pretty much the same code for setting the text anyway

```
$('.ms-vb').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) 
        this.textContent = this.textContent.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: And no jQuery needed

Comment: @j08691 don't mind jQuery since it is loaded for other stuff i've got

Comment: @rob.m - yes, it can be made to work with `querySelectorAll` and a simple loop as well. Point being, you target the node, and modify it in place, there's no need for a clone

Comment: @rob.m If plain javascript can do it as simple as this, use it and you save workload client side

Comment: Here's how to do it with multiple BR's -> https://jsfiddle.net/vqg9xgmw/2/

Comment: ok fair enough @LGSon, will accept this then for future users

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the text first from `td`, you can do something like this:

```js
var td_clone = $('.ms-vb').clone();
var elements = $('.ms-vb').children();
$('span', td_clone).remove();
$('br', td_clone).remove();
$('.ms-vb').html('');
$('.ms-vb').append(elements);
var name = $.trim(td_clone.text());
$("td").append(name.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="80%" style="padding-bottom: 3px" class="ms-vb">
            <span class="ms-announcementtitle">
                title is here
            </span>
            <br>
            by hey
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var td_clone = $('.ms-vb').clone();
console.log(td_clone);
$('span', td_clone).remove();
$('br', td_clone).remove();
var name = $.trim(td_clone.text());
$("td").append(name.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: hey saw your update, did you actually test it? the result is exactly as per the question code http://jsfiddle.net/Cba4m/39/